# How to edit my /etc/sysctl.conf file?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, text-editor, editing

In one of the labs for learning Linux system administrator I have to do :

5. Now change the value by modifying `/etc/sysctl.conf` and force the system to activate this setting file without a reboot.
6. Check that this worked properly.

here is what i must do:

> Add the following line to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:
>
> ```
> net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1
> ```
>
> and then do:
>
> ```
> $ sysctl -p
> ```

how to do this and with which text editor?

Comment: view current settings before doing file edit by issuing  `sysctl -a|grep icmp_echo`

Answer (score 13):

**1.** You can add this line using nano or vim from terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

where you then scroll down and add the line by hand then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to end editing. You will be asked if you want to save, confirm that by pressing <kbd>y</kbd> and then once <kbd>return</kbd> to save.

Same way you can reverse your changes.

**2.** You can add it as well this way:

```
echo "net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```

For reversing this refer to solution 1.